# Explaining the Summation Process

Tags: probability, summation

So I have two separate summations, with the only difference being the first variable being squared in the second one.  Can somebody explain to me how they got from the second to the third step on both.  I don't see how this is occurring.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I got $3p(1+2p)$ for the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just insert the values for $y_1$. In the first case this yields 
$3p(1-p)^2+6p^2(1-p)+3p^3=3p(1-2p+p^2)+6p^2-6p^3+3p^3=3p-6p^2+3p^3+6p^2-6p^3+3p^3=3p$. 
The second one can be obtained analogously.

Comment: $+1$, but I got $3p(1+2p)$ for the second one

Comment: What do you mean by +1?  The second one is: $3p(1-p)^2+12p^2(1-p)+9p^3=3p(1-2p+p^2)+12p^2-12p^3+9p^3=3p-6p^2+3p^3+12p^2-12p^3 +9p^3=3p+6p^2=3p(1+2p)$. Ad you can see your calculation is right and the sign has to be a +

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  By $+1$, I meant that I upvoted your answer.  Thanks for verifying that the second one is $3p(1\color{red}{+2}p)$; that is different from what OP wrote

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for explaining